# How to integrate own API docs in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, documentation, sandcastle, api-doc

We create API docs with Sandcastle (Help File Builder) and now want to integrate them into Visual Studio 2008. How can the API be integrated or added as an external (web) resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google for "Sandcastle H2Reg" to read about other people's experiences.

But personally, because starting up VS2008 Help after integrating a new Help Collection is as slow as molasses, I prefer sticking to CHM format for my documentation.  YMMV of course.

Comment: It seems like CHM files are still the best option. It is a bit poor what Microsoft offers in this area.